# Drawing a direction on Google maps is not continuous

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-maps, google-directions-api

I'm using these settings to create a direction from a location to another:

```
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
polylineOptions.width(15);
polylineOptions.color(colorPrimary);
mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions.addAll(points));
```

And on the map, it looks like this:

https://ibb.co/D13xc0T

How to draw a continuous line from one point to another without those interruptions?

This is the code that gets the points:

```
if (direction != null) {
    List<Route> routes = direction.routes;
    Route route = routes.get(0);
    List<Leg> legs = route.legs;
    Leg leg = legs.get(0);
    List<Step> steps = leg.steps;
    for (Step step : steps) {
        String point = step.polyline.points;
        List<LatLng> points = PolyUtil.decode(point);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `points`. What did you add to polyline?

Comment: @MaratZangiev `points` is a list of `List<LatLng>`. Is it not correct?

Comment: Yes, it is right. Provide your code of `points`. What is inside the `points` variables?

Comment: @MaratZangiev Please see my updated question.

Comment: In code that you provide your `points` variable is created inside `for`-loop. Are you sure that it is the `points` variable that is in your code above? (It is not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add many `PolylineOptions` to map. They are not connected to each over and so you get this interruptions. Try to add all decoded paths to one common array.

Your edited code:

```java
ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
for (Step step : steps) {
        String point = step.polyline.points;
        points.addAll(PolyUtil.decode(point));
    }

PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
polylineOptions.width(15);
polylineOptions.color(colorPrimary);
mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions.addAll(points));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Let me try your solution and I get you back.

Comment: I just did what you advised me but it only creates a single part of my entire line, the last part. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Add all of your parts to `points` array. And after that draw polyline. It should be drawn without interruptions. Or provide your whole code if I understand you not right

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, it works fine for me. You can add multiple point also.

```
mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(PointA).add(PointB).width(8f).color(Color.RED));
```

Comment: Let me try and get you back.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I get the same behaviour. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: give your point plz. I would like to see the behaviour where it's broken

Comment: Are U getting proper value on 'points'? ... would you please print all values

Comment: Yes, I get proper values.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with broken polylines. After not finding a solution here, I stumbled across a closed issue [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/issues/147). If you just add all points of all steps as given by the result of an call to Googles API you won't get a continuous line, because the endpoints will be added twice. Once as end of a step and a second time as beginning of the next step. That is why there is no single continuous line and why you have to remove duplicates. In Kotlin this is pretty easy by calling `allPoints = allPoints.distinct() as ArrayList<LatLng>`. Calling this will keep the order of the points, but remove any duplicates in the list.